# Crashlytics doesn't work after migration to Fabric

Tags: android, sdk, crashlytics

I use Crashlytics SDK in my app (with Mopub and Twitter SDK's). All work normal, but after last update I dont get message with crashes.

**Before update**
[image]
**After update (only last app version)**
[image]

In my project I make all instructions from manual:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
...
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.mopub.sdk.android:mopub:3.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

In my code I start Crashlytics in **MainActivity**:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

P.S. Fabric plugin dont show no errors and alerts and show me crashes from previous app version.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided it this way: I remove my app from [fabric.io](http://fabric.io), re-install fabric plugin in Android Studio, and change this lines in my **build.gradle** file:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.mopub.sdk.android:mopub:3.3.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

and I change this line in my Application class:

```
Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new MoPub(), new Crashlytics());
```

Next I run my app and test this with this line:

```
throw new RuntimeException();
```

[image]

Comment: I dont why, but me need change my branch in SourceTree for normal work Fabric plugin.